# In Anylogic: recalculate route cyclically when not in idle state

Tags: anylogic, agent

I have problems with the animation of my transporter agents in anylogic. They get stuck and then they no longer move in the simulation. However, the fleet thinks they are busy and this ruins my results.

I would like my agents to recalculate their route cyclically when they are not idle.
In the `TransporterFleet-Block` under "Actions" I put in `on transporters state changed`":

```
if (agent.getState() != TransporterState.IDLE){
    agent.eventRecalculation.restart();
}
if (agent.getState() == TransporterState.IDLE){
    agent.eventRecalculation.reset();
}
```

with `eventRecalculation` being a cyclic event that happens every 20 seconds. This is reset at the start-up of the model to stop it from happening from the beginning.

Anylogic now gives me the error code: `agent cannot be resolved.`
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `on transporters state changed` field you refer to the transporter as `unit` not `agent`